# log4j RollingFileAppender not writing to log until application close

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

We're using log4j 1.2.17 via slf4j-log4j12 1.7.7 with Java 8. I'm running the application from within Eclipse 4.4.1 on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Our root `log4j.properties` file looks like this:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p (%c{1}) [%d] - %l: %m%n
```

In the application we set up a rolling file appender based upon the configuration:

```
EnhancedPatternLayout patternLayout = new EnhancedPatternLayout("%-5p (%c{1}) [%d] - %l: %m%n");
RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(patternLayout, logPath, true);
rollingFileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(5);
rollingFileAppender.setMaxFileSize(5MB);
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
```

That works nicely... when the application is finally closed! While the application is running the log file sits at zero bytes, which isn't very helpful.

(In this version of our application we switched from using straight log4j to using slf4j->log4j. I don't remember offhand if the behavior was different before we switched.)

*Update:* I've traced through the creation of the actual writer. log4j creates a `FileOutputStream`, then wraps that in an `OutputStreamWriter`, which it then wraps in a `CountingQuietWriter` which is called by the appender. The `bufferedIO` flag is turned off. I have also traced through writing a log message, and it seems to be written normally to the `CountingQuietWriter`->`OutputStreamWriter`->`FileOutputStream`. Yet nothing appears in the log file until I close the application.

Why isn't the application writing to the log immediately, or at least every so often after the buffer gets full?

Comment: Humm... This works fine for me. I'm using Windows 7 with Java 8 and slf4j 1.7.7

Comment: Does it work if you configure this appender in log4j.properties ?

Comment: Are these logs from application or from tests? If from tests, are you running them from surefire/failsafe?

I had exactly the same problem because of parallel execution tests in application, changing surefire/failsafe configuration helped.

Comment: These logs are from the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, this could very well just be your OS/filesystem/storage appliance/etc issue, or the application your using to view the file size, not retrieving/replicating/updating file metadata...and the data might actually be there.  The file system may only replicate/report metadata after your write lock is released, for example.

When you open the file (read-only) while the application is running, do you see data, despite the reported file size?

Comment: No, when I open the file while the application is running, I do not see data.

Comment: Well then...now im gonna test this:) what OS and filesystem are you using?

Comment: I just tested on a Win7/NTFS and an ubuntu ext3 fs, both worked...WIN7/NTFS did, as I mentioned, not reflect the file metadata size but when I opened it read-only all log messages were indeed there.  Eventually, the metadata did update, though.  Just let me know your environment info and I'll see what I can do to test.

Comment: Ah, OK, this was indeed the problem and I didn't clearly explain my procedure. I opened the log file on NTFS and watched it in EmEditor on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. Because EmEditor didn't automatically update when new information was logged, I thought it wasn't being flushed to the file. But I didn't realize that if the file system metadata wasn't updating, EmEditor itself wouldn't know to reload the information. When I actually closed down EmEditor and re-opened the log file (or told EmEditor to reload manually), the content was there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, forcing the appender to write each line whenever it's logged by the application :

```
rollingFileAppender.setImmediateFlush(true);
rollingFileAppender.setBufferedIO(false);
```

The weird thing is that these values are the default one, but you can try it anyway.

Comment: I've updated the question after verifying the `bufferedIO` flag is turned off, even tracing through the code.

Comment: Does it work if you configure this appender in log4j.properties ?